# Arraylist .add is not working inside loop

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having some sort of problem with the homeContent Arraylist. Have a look at the code...

```
        ArrayList<String> homeContent=new ArrayList<>(); //its actually a global list but I'm showing inside just show I've declared and initialised it.
        contentDb=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("home");
        contentDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    tag=ds.getValue(String.class);
                    homeContent.add(tag);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Connecting to the Server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        for(int i=0;i<homeContent.size();i++){
            Log.i("Entry",homeContent.get(i));
        }
```

So I used Log.i to track where the problem is and so I found out that the elements are being added in the list but as soon as it comes out of the loop and the valueEventListener function, it's back to having 0 elements in it.

**EDIT:** Turns out nothing inside that loop is staying permanently

Comment: Your for loop is executed before the event fires.

Comment: please elaborate..

Comment: Your code just states, "when the data changes, add stuff to the ArrayList`, but then you proceed to just log the contents, before this event even might happened.

Comment: No actually the function does execute and I tried logging the values inside the loop and it worked, so the event did occur.

Comment: Yeah, when you log inside the event, it will only log when the event happens, because that is what you told it to do. Log in both places, and log before and after you enter each loop.

Comment: In other words: Your for loop is not executed after your event handler runs, but instead before.

Comment: ah got it!, so how do I fix it?

Comment: Run it in your event handler.

Comment: cool! sounds like it will work

Comment: Thanks! it works!

Answer (score -1):

Ok so thanks to  Johannes Kuhn, the problem has been solved, actually the for loop was being executed after the event handler was being called so I had to put the loop inside the event handler.

Answer (score -2):

```
ArrayList<String>   arrayList = null;  
contentDb=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("home");
    contentDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                tag=ds.getValue(String.class);
                arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                arrayList.add(tag); // Add into list like this
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Connecting to the Server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Better you can add that value into list like I have shared above.

Comment: but I want to use the list out of the loop, if I do this, I wouldn't be able to access it from outside

Comment: @PrabavPandya Try to add the global reference with null which I have given above.